# Git fix merge conflict by deleting files in master, is this possible?

Tags: git

I have a conflict with master with one of my branch, there's one file which conflicts. Can I delete the file in master and merge with branch to get the file back? Will this fix the conflict? Thanks

Comment: Deleting the file in the `master` branch most probably won't resolve the conflict but will produce a new different conflict. Can you provide the full output of `git merge ...` and `git status`?

Answer (score -1):

(Side note, but this is important: don't think so much about *branches* in the first place.  Files are in *commits*.  Git stores *commits*.  Git merges *commits*.  Everything is all about *commits*, and branch names like `master` just serve to *find* the commits.)

If you were to delete a file, you would do this in a commit.  (That commit may or may not be contained within the set of commits reachable by the name `master`; in the method you're thinking of, it would be in that set of comits.)  But this won't really help: you'd just get a different conflict, specifically a modify/delete conflict.  The answer to conflicts is never a complicated "delete the file here or there" kind of thing.  It's always to *resolve* the conflict.

You should start at the beginning, which is this: Merging is about *combining changes*.  This involves finding a *merge base* commit.  You tell Git to merge a commit—usually by naming a branch, as in `git merge otherbranch`, but that still names one specific commit.  Git finds this merge base commit on its own as commit #1, uses your current commit—the tip of your current branch—as commit #2, and uses the commit you named as commit #3.

Each commit stores a full and complete snapshot of all of your files, so before Git can *combine* changes, Git first has to *find* changes.  This involves running `git diff`, which can compare two commits.  It can only compare *two* commits though!<sup>1</sup>  So the merge base that `git merge` chooses has to be on *both branches:*

```
          I--J   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

If you're on `branch1` and run `git merge branch2`, the three commits that Git will use at this point are `H`, `J`, and `L`: `J` is your current commit, at the tip of `branch1`; `L` is the commit at the tip of `branch2`, which you are merging; and `H` is the *best shared* commit that's on *both* branches, so `H` is the merge base.

Git now, in effect, runs:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # what we changed on branch1
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>   # what they changed on branch2
```

The process of merging is now the simple-ish job of taking, for each file that we both changed, the set of changes we both made, and combining those changes.  Those combined changes then get applied to whatever was in the file in commit `H`—not to our commit `J`, nor to their commit `L`, but rather to the *base* commit!  That way, we get *both* sets of changes.

A conflict occurs because both you and they changed the *same lines* of the same file.  You and they may also have changed *different* lines of that same file; Git will be able to combine those on its own.  It's only where your changes and their changes "touch" (overlap or abut), and you and they didn't make the *exact same* change, that you get a conflict.

While the conflict is ongoing, Git does give you access to *all three* of the original input files.  What you see in your work-tree file is its best attempt to combine changes, complete with conflict markers; but you can access the merge base copy of the file, your `branch1` commit-`J` copy of the file, and their `branch2` commit-`L` copy of the file, if you like.  (The `git mergetool` command does this sort of thing for you, extracting the three copies of the file and running your chosen merge tool.  I tend not to use this though: I usually just edit the work-tree copy directly.)

If you are absolutely sure you want to throw away *all* of your changes—even those that don't conflict with the other side's changes—you can do that pretty easily at this point, using `git checkout --theirs`.  For instance, if the conflicts are in file `lib.py`:

```
git checkout --theirs lib.py
```

will extract the #3 copy of the file (from commit `L`) into the work-tree copy.  You can then examine it, make sure it's good, and then use `git add lib.py` to mark the conflict resolved.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git does have a `git diff` that can compare three or more commits, producing what it calls a *combined diff*, but that's not really relevant here: it doesn't work for merges.

---

#### What happens if you *do* delete the file before merging?

Suppose you went ahead with your plan.  You'd make a new commit on branch `branch1` in which this file—let's continue to call it `lib.py` for concreteness—doesn't exist:

```
          I--J--N   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

Git would now `git diff` commit `H` vs commit `N` to see what you changed.  Among whatever other changes it finds, it would find that you *deleted* `lib.py` entirely.  Then Git would diff commit `H` vs commit `L`.  It must find some change in `lib.py` here, because when you tried the merge with commit `J`, it had a conflict, and it can only have a conflict if both you and they made changes to the same lines of that file.  So there will be some change Git will want to apply with `H` vs `L`.

What you will get is a *modify/delete* conflict.  Git may temporarily go with the removal, or may leave you with their version of `lib.py` from commit `L`.  If Git removed the file, you would now need to `git checkout --theirs lib.py` to get theirs.  If Git left you theirs in your work-tree, you would not have to do anything here—saving you one step here, but at the cost of the extra step of making commit `N`.  Then you would `git add lib.py` to resolve the conflict.

You've just done pretty much the exact same amount of work!  Why not just do it the right way, without making an extra commit?

Comment: why such a bible to answer?